# Installing sikuli on Mac OSX using pip command

Tags: python, pip, cython, sikuli

I tried to install sikuli on Mac OSX using the following command:

pip install sikuli
But it is shown that I have to install Cytho first.

So I tried to install Cython using the commnd:
pip install Cython

but got the following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cython.py'
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --user cython` *or* `sudo pip install cython`

Regular users do not have permissions to write to system directories (`/Library/Python/..`). Either install only for current user, or `sudo` it to install in system path.

Note - this has nothing to do with cython.